# Scope of variables Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variables, properties, scope

Do variables declared in methods get erased after the method call is done? Ie If i have the method "someMethod" and every time it is called i want to return a different NSString from a stack property will the method return the next object on the stack or will it keep returned the first index since x is erased at the end of the method call. I know if C that variables are erased after function calls, is it the same in objective c? Would using a seperate property for the variable x some this problem? Thanks

```
(Double) someMethod{
int x;
[self.stack objectAtIndex:x];
x++;
}
```

After reading the comments I tried creating a property to replace x and here is what I wrote but I get an error warning stating "local declaration of "_location" hides instance variable" What does this mean?

```
@property (nonatomic) int location;
@synthesize location=_location;

-(int) location{
    if(!_location){
        int _location = 0;
     //warning is here 
    return _location;
     }
_location++;
return _location;

}

 (Double) someMethod{
int x;
[self.stack objectAtIndex:self.location];
x++;
}
```

Comment: The OP's snippet deals with primitives, but what happens to *object* variables once they go out of scope is a big, fascinating question. The quesion, as posed, is wide enough to warrant that discussion.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev -- An object variable is no different from a primitive variable in this regard -- the validity of the variable lasts only from first assignment to the point that it goes out of scope.  Of course, the object potentially addressed by the variable is a different topic, but it has nothing to do with the scope of the *variable*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do variables declared in methods get erased after the method call is done?

Yes

Objective C methods are implemented "on top" of C functions, so the same rules apply. In particular, your code exhibits undefined behavior (reading of uninitialized variable).

To fix this issue, add an instance variable `x` in place of the *automatic* variable that your code snippet currently declares.

---

*automatic* is the "official" name of "stack" variables, i.e. variables that you declare inside your methods / functions.

Comment: Actually, "automatic variable" is a more appropriate term for a variable scoped within a method.

Comment: @HotLicks in what situation could you possibly have a stack variable outside of a method scope?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII -- The main point is that the term is "automatic".  Beyond that, automatic variables can be implemented without a stack.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, this is a very good point. That was the main point of mentioning the official name in the first place.

Comment: Im still not sure what an automatic variable is?

Comment: @TerrelGibson Automatic variables are variables that you declare inside a function or a method without a `static` qualifier. In your example, `x` is an automatic variable. The scope of this variables is the block where they are declared. As soon as the control goes past the end of the block, the variable becomes inaccessible, and its value cannot be retrieved. Automatic variables are allocated in the automatic storage area (as opposed to the static storage area and the dynamic storage area). The automatic area is often, but not always, implemented using the hardware stack of the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the lifetime of local variables is limited to the time the enclosing function is executing (with exceptions for *blocks*, but you're not using those in this case).

Your counter `x` is probably best as an object property, if you want to maintain its value between calls to `someMethod`.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to your question about the warning...

It is just saying that when you declare inside your if in method location()

```
int _location = 0;
```

this local variable has the same name as the property you created earlier

```
@syntenshize location = _location
```

Thus it gets confusing (for the programmer) to know which one he is using at the moment.

The compiler will understand that inside the if _location is an int  ... and outside the if _location is your property.