# Why isn't my basic class working?

Tags: objective-c

This is driving me crazy. I have a class:

```
@interface qanda : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *quote;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *author;

@end
```

And yes, I did synthesise them in the other file.

And then in my Viewdidload file I declared some objects.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    qanda *qanda1 = [[qanda alloc] init];
    qanda1.quote = @"All our dreams can come true – if we have the courage to pursue          them. ";
    qanda1.author = @"Walt Disney";
}
```

There is a short extract of my ViewDidLoad file.

However when I try to access this object's strings I get an error and I don't know why.

```
self.quote.text = qanda.quote;`
```

(quote is an outlet by the way)
The error I get is: "Use of undeclared identifier  'qanda1' ; did you mean 'qanda'?

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to access qanda1? It's only in scope within viewDidLoad. You'll have to use a member variable if you want to keep track of it more generally.

Comment: I guess you have to include the required delegates in your .h file !

Comment: It also helps to name your classes from capital letter so you don't mix them up with instance variables later in the code.

Comment: @Luke  thank-you! I realised that I couldn't try to access the object out of the function I had declared it in.

Comment: Why do you say `self.quote.text = qanda.quote;`, when qanda is a class name, not a variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see here, your `qanda *qanda1` is limited to the `viewDidLoad` method. Once that method returns, `qanda1` no longer exists.

In your view controller's header file, declare a property for `qanda1`.

```
@class Qanda;    
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
    .
    .
    .
@property Qanda *qanda1;
@end
```

In the implementation file "MyViewController.m):

```
#import "Qanda.h"

@implementation MyViewController
.
.
.
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    Qanda *qanda1 = [[Qanda alloc] init];
    qanda1.quote = @"All our dreams can come true – if we have the courage to pursue          them. ";
    qanda1.author = @"Walt Disney";
}

.
.
.
@end
```

This way, you have access to `qanda1` throughout the lifetime of `MyViewController`. You can now perform your `self.quote.text = qanda1.quote;` anytime after `viewDidLoad` has been called.

I would recommend on reading up on variable scope ([here is a good starting point on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751099/620197)) so that you get complete understanding of what is happening here.

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in comments to your question, following some basic naming conventions might help to distinguish between instance variables and class names. (for [Objective C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH), but most languages follow the same, if not similar patterns).

Following the usual conventions, your "qanda" class would look like this:

```
@interface Qanda : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *quote;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *author;

@end
```

Comment: Thank- you very much Mike D. You helped me greatly!